# Bonus to trade route - valid on existing routes?

Tags: civilization-6

Are bonuses to trade routes (Sukiennice) granted on the existing routes or just on the ones established after building is completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bonuses for trade routes are applied to existing and future ones. They can be provided by anything (including the unique Polish building).